# extra output in zsh when define git log output format

Tags: git, zsh

when I try using

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" --graph --date=short
```

in zsh, there's always some extra output like:

```
27m/Users/tyraeltong/tmp/git-immersion/hello [n]' --graph --date=...* b1ca0c6 2012-01-08 | Added README (HEAD, master) [Tyrael Tong]
* 6844069 2012-01-08 | Added a Rakefile [Tyrael Tong]
* 99430f3 2012-01-08 | Moved hello.rb to lib [Tyrael Tong]
* da616c8 2012-01-08 | Add an author/email info [Tyrael Tong]
* d997079 2012-01-06 | Added a comment (v1) [Tyrael Tong]
* ea557cd 2012-01-06 | Added a default value (v1-beta) [Tyrael Tong]
* 0111ccd 2012-01-06 | First Commit [Tyrael Tong]
```

How could I remove the `27m/Users/tyraeltong/tmp/git-immersion/hello [n]' --graph --date=...`?

Comment: Looks like something in your environment (possibly your prompt string) is messing something up. Doesn't have anything to do with git afaikt.

Comment: I do have the same effect with a custom prompt, so Mat is probably right.

Comment: I concur, this has to be related to a fancy prompt. What are your prompt settings?

Comment: Yes I have a zsh setup with oh-my-zsh, and use superjarin theme. This may relate to the fancy prompt setting in the superjarin but, it's wired because when I use .gitconfig file and set something like "hist=log --pretty.....", and juse "git hist", there's no extra output!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is discussed in [this oh-my-zsh issue](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/521). There is also a temporary fix:

> All problems are because lib/termsupport.zsh lines 12. 
>    for a temporary fix, simply comment this line. this line try to set caption on terminal window. so its not a big deal to remove it :)

In the last comment there is a link to another fix:

> You could also fix it like stated in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zsh/+bug/435336/comments/2

(note: it is better that you go to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zsh/+bug/435336/ as “/comments/2” URL displays only the second comment and nothing else)

Comment: You can also set `DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"` in `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 4):

Inserting `""` between `%` and `s` solved it for me:

`git log --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %""s%d [%an]" --graph --date=short`

Answer (score 1):

I tried to alias a slightly different command and had exactly the same issue.

This solved it for me:

```
alias glp='git log --pretty=format:"%h %an %ar - %"s""'
```

So by just putting **s** in quotation marks the output isn't prepended with garbage à la *27m* anymore.

Comment: Wondering how all of you are observing this behavior? I have `setopt promptpercent` and just the same command as @Tyrael Tong produces no additional output, neither using my own configuration, nor with `zsh -f`. The fix must be something different. Ah, and I don’t use `oh-my-zsh`.

Comment: Then it might probably be oh-my-zsh since I also use it.

Comment: I would suggest using `set -x` and examining output prior to problematic behavior.

Comment: This issue is on oh-my-zsh bug tracker. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not your prompt. This happens to me with zsh and an empty PS1. zsh is doing something to expand %s thinking that in this case it is part of your prompt. It's fixed with a `setopt nopromptpercent`, but that will likely mess up your prompt.

A possibly non-portable solution is to prompt-escape the %s. Try running this instead:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %%s%d [%an]" --graph --date=short
```